# Index of minimum element in a std::list

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, std, listiterator

If I have a `std::vector<int>`, I can obtain the index of the minimum element by subtracting two iterators:

```
int min_index = std::min_element(vec.begin(), vec.end()) - vec.begin();
```

However, with containers that don't have random access iterators, for example a `std::list<int>`, this doesn't work.  Sure, it is possible to do something like

```
int min_index = std::difference(l.begin(), std::min_element(l.begin(), l.end()));
```

but then I have to iterate twice through the list.

Can I get the index of the element with the minimum value with STL algorithms by only iterating once through the list or do I have to code my own for-loop?

Comment: Why do you need the index of an element in a `std::list`?

Comment: You could write an iterator that wraps `list::iterator` and keeps track of its index as it goes. It would have limited use, since inserting/removing elements from the container would invalidate the indexes stored in your iterators, but you could use `min_element` and other algorithms on it, then grab the index out of the return value.

Comment: You could use `std::set` or sort your container and always know where the minimum element is ...

Comment: If you want to do this, a `list` is probably the wrong data structure for the job.

Comment: I need a list because (a) the order is important (so i can't use a set) and (b) the iterators need to be valid after inserting an element. Indexes are only rarely needed for the user.

Comment: In you want to iterate only once, that is you want O(n), complexity, a for loop will do also O(n), for a static list, i.e. no elements are added. If you do add elements, then the index might change, and you will have find the index again by performing O(n) comparisons. If you would use `std::vector` instead the index would be preserved upon insertion and you would only have to perform O(1) comparisons every time instead of O(n). I don't think that you can do it with std::list if elements can be added /removed to the list .

Comment: @Niklas B. : Maybe he has his reasons... i.e. that is the container he has to work upon.

Comment: @g24l: I agree, but I don't think that this could be solved in one line without writing additional code, so maybe switching the data structure is a better idea.

Comment: If the indexes are only rarely needed, why are you concerned about the difference between a O(2n) loop and a O(n) loop for finding them?  Your `std::distance` example, while theoretically slower than a single pass for-loop, is pretty much guaranteed to be correct on the first try.

Comment: @NiklasB. : well I don't disagree, if he can change the container, then I would advise him to do so. However, if for some reason, the `std::list` is the output of some blackbox process, which he may not modify, then we this is a problem to consider.

Comment: I have to say though, that there is no sense in getting the index for any practical reason I can think of. Finding the minimum value, that would be of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to write your own function, for example:

```
template <class ForwardIterator>
  std::size_t min_element_index ( ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last )
{
  ForwardIterator lowest = first;
  std::size_t index = 0;
  std::size_t i = 0;
  if (first==last) return index;
  while (++first!=last) {
    ++i;
    if (*first<*lowest) {
      lowest=first;
      index = i;
    }
  }
  return index;
}
```