# If I use list instead of vector in the following code, why compilation is failed in the line where I try to perform subtraction in between iterators?

Tags: c++, stl

The following code works fine:

```
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v1;
    vector<int>::iterator it, low, up;

    for (int i=1; i<=10; i++)
        v1.push_back(i);
    cout << "elements are- \n";
    for(it=v1.begin(); it!=v1.end(); it++)
        cout << *it << " ";
    sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());

    low = lower_bound(v1.begin(), v1.end(), 3);
    up = upper_bound(v1.begin(), v1.end(), 6);

    cout << "\npos of low- " << (low-v1.begin()) << "\n";
    cout << "pos of up- " << (up-v1.begin()) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But if the type of container is changed from vector to list, compilation fails. It shows the following error:

```
In function 'int main()': 20:35: error: no match for 'operator-'
    (operand types are 'std::list<int>::iterator {aka
    std::_List_iterator<int>}' and 'std::list<int>::iterator {aka
    std::_List_iterator<int>}')
```

Comment: Using a binary search on a linked list would defeat its purpose, wouldn't it? In other words, if you know what binary search and linked lists are, then why do you expect that to work?

Comment: This is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687957/index-of-minimum-element-in-a-stdlist), but the asker in the other question already knows why it doesn't work; he wants a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::lower_bound` works just fine. (Although it's not as efficient as it could be.) What doesn't is your attempt to subtract one iterator from another, since `std::list::iterator` is not a random access iterator and does not support subtraction.

For future reference, if you post a piece of code and an error with a line number, you should indicate somehow which line in your code that is. SO doesn't contain line numbers in its code snippets, and even if it did, we'd have no guarantee that they actually line up with the code you compiled (i.e. you didn't snip some lines somewhere).

Comment: ....Thanks a lot for your input and suggestion. I missed that point, it actually showed error in that line where I attempted to subtract the iterators. But is there any way to get the position in the list without subtracting the iterator?

Comment: `std::distance`

Comment: @JayS, It'll be linear because that's how linked lists work. This raises some red flags on data structure choice.